# Front page hero background image improperly scaled on Mobile

Tags: android, ios, css, wordpress, responsive-design

On my wordpress site, the background for the front page hero is improperly scaled on mobile devices (iOS and Android). It only shows a fraction of the image as opposed to the full image. 
I have tried:

-changing the resolution and sizing of the image

-[Unwanted scaling on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313229/unwanted-scaling-on-mobile-devices) (Inserted the meta tag but no changes propegated, yes I cleared cache too)

-[Site scaling on a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062188/site-scaling-on-a-mobile-device) (I tried testing CSS changes through USB debugging but it did not work)

I am using the Brooklyn theme created by United Themes. The site also utilizes Visual Composer.

Site: https://www.wearerubbish.com

Current CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.parallax-section {
    background-position: center center !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-y !important;
    /* background-attachment: fixed !important; */
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example would be nice so we can take a look at the code, but usually I fix those problems by adding a `max-width` property with a value of `100vw` if the hero is full width and it is a `<img>` tag. But if the image is a `background-image` a `background-size: cover;` will do just fine.

Comment: can you provide page url?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this css

```
.hero .parallax-scroll-container { 
    background-size: contain!important;
}
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction but now there is a bunch of blank space on the top and bottom of the image